# How to use zurb foundation Menu in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I would love to use zurb foundation Navigation menus in bootstrap project but i am not sure how i can or is it possible to integrate zurb foundation menu for example one show in this example in bootstrap 2.3 http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html

I am facing couple of issue with boostrap menus like hover effect even after implementing few different methods i am still not happy with the bootstrap menu as i was both hover & click event to work effectively on both desktop and mobile devices.

Example which i have set up after [here](http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/TestPage4.htm) show one of the issue i face on mobile devices. you can try it for you self

So far i have see hover & click event works very smoothly on both desktop & mobile device.

I would appreciate help in this regard so that i can integrate only zurb foundation navigation menus in bootstrap project

What are the minimum files that i need to use beside app.css for menu to works like a charm.

Comment: I agree with vgarcias below, you cannot decouple(easily) the nav bar functionality, not only does it have css, but also the JS associated with it does some redrawing to help it position correctly.  If there are specific styling aspects that you like from the navbar in foundation that you want to pull you might be best off hunting for those.  Otherwise maybe you want to take a peek at bootstrap3 like vgarcias suggested, it does have a better implemented nav than bootstrap 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the zurb-foundation download at http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php, first uncheck "all foundation components" then just check the "top bar" option.

Now, to use the top-bar foundation 4 within bootstrap, try to put the your top-bar class outside the div "cointainer"

Bootstrap 3 has a better nav-bar.

Comment: I only need to replace bootstrap nav as it works fine for click event. While i need both click & hover event.. I tried several tutorial unfortunately they where not of much help to completely solve my issue. any ways i am working now on a custom menu navigation that seem to have addressed my problem which i was facing with BS. Thanks for your reply..